# Перевешивание (поменять местами) элементов grid при перезагрузке

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть плитки с информацией, они расположены в grid сетке и все имеют `id="item"` и одинаковую структуру. 
Каким образом я могу перемешивать их с помощью JS?
возможно ли делать перемешивание при перезагрузке (то есть пользователь зашел- стандартный порядок, перезагрузил -иной)?

Пример плитки

```
<div id="item">
   <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
     <img >
        <div class="DataItem">
            <div id="Name">
                <h2>"***********</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="Datatime">
                <h4>"***********</h4>
            </div>
         </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант: сверстать на flex, а с помощью js при перезагрузке страницы изменять класс .order-***, где вместо *** цифра от 1 до 12.
https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.3.1/utilities/flex/#order

Comment: Это не подходит,. сайт уже готов и это должно быть фичей, поэтому нужно в минимум действий на странице. Я представляю это как: взять в массив все эти блоки с rendom вернуть но я не знаю как это реализовать, и возможно ли это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так. Берем все элементы, сортируем их в случайном порядке, добавляем в контейнер.

Пример.

```js
function shuffle(container) {
  [...container.children].sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1).forEach(f => container.appendChild(f));
}

shuf.addEventListener('click', () => shuffle(container));
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>3</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>4</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>5</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <a class="lLink_item" href="***********">
      <img>
      <div class="DataItem">
        <div id="Name">
          <h2>6</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="shuf">Перемешать</button>
```

Comment: Вместо `Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1` я бы записал `Math.random() - 0.5`

Comment: @Deonis каждому свое. Кто-то мог бы написать `Array.from` вместо `[...]` и много чего еще можно написать по другому.